# Como contar las palabras duplicadas de archivos en un folder

Tags: java, lista

Ayuda por favor.

En este código estoy tratando que al momento de escribir una palabra (en este caso "home") me lance los nombres de los archivos que contienen dicha palabra, ademas de indicar cuantas veces se repite en ese archivo.

Actualmente mi código busca la palabra y me menciona los archivos que contienen la palabra, más no me dice el numero de repeticiones.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File dir = new File("/Users/Adan/Desktop/Files/"); // directory = target directory.
        int counter = 0;//aaaaa


        if(dir.exists()){ // Directory exists then proceed.

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("jose"); // keyword = keyword to search in files.
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of files.

            System.out.println("La palabra " + p + " esta dentro de estos archivos:");


            for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
                if(!f.isFile()){
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                    fis.read(data);
                    String text = new String(data);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                    if(m.find()){
                        list.add(f.getName()); // add file to found-keyword list.
                    }
                    fis.close();
                } 
                catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("\n\t Error processing file : "+f.getName()+ counter);
                }
            }
            for (String listado : list) { 
                System.out.println(listado);//Lista
            }
        } // IF directory exists then only process.
        else{
            System.out.println("\n Directory doesn't exist.");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `find()` busca la siguiente ocurrencia del patrón, si lo encuentra devuelve `true`. En tu código lo usas una vez para comprobar si la palabra existe dentro del archivo. Para contar las palabras puedes llamarlo varias veces hasta que devuelva `false` indicando que ya no hay más ocurrencias en el archivo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File dir = new File("/Users/Adan/Desktop/Files/"); // directory = target directory.
        int counter = 0;//aaaaaterminal


        if(dir.exists()){ // Directory exists then proceed.

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("jose"); // keyword = keyword to search in files.
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of files.

            //Lista para guardar las repeticiones por archivo
            ArrayList<Integer> repeticiones = new ArrayList<Integer>();


            System.out.println("La palabra " + p + " esta dentro de estos archivos:");


            for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
                if(!f.isFile()){
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                    fis.read(data);
                    String text = new String(data);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);


                    //contador para guardar las repeticiones por archivo
                    int contadorRepeticiones = 0;
                    //contar todas las repeticiones de la palabra en el archivo
                    while(m.find()){
                        contadorRepeticiones++;
                    }

                    //Si hay una o más repeticiones agregar el nombre del archivo
                    // y total de repeticiones a sus correspondientes listas
                    if(contadorRepeticiones > 0){
                        list.add(f.getName()); // add file to found-keyword list.
                        repeticiones.add(contadorRepeticiones);
                    }

                    fis.close();
                } 
                catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("\n\t Error processing file : "+f.getName()+ counter);
                }
            }

            //recorrer la lista de archivos e imprimir el nombre junto con las
            //repeticiones
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
               System.out.println(list.get(i) + " aparece: " + repeticiones.get(i) + " veces");//Lista

            }
        } // IF directory exists then only process.
        else{
            System.out.println("\n Directory doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
```

**Solución 2:**

Puedes reemplazar este código:

```
int contadorRepeticiones = 0;
//contar todas las repeticiones de la palabra en el archivo
while(m.find()){
   contadorRepeticiones++;
}
```

Por esto:

```
int contadorRepeticiones = (int)m.results().count();
```